# How to change className for ViewChild in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I've added a `ng2-select` dependency in my app, but I'd like to tweak the style of ng2-select a little bit. It there any possible way I can add some custom className to this `ng2-select` component in my app?

Directly tweaking css is unfavourable because there are more than one ng2-select in the app and I only want to tweak one of them.

```
@Component({
  template: `<ng2-select [class]="my-class"></ng2-select>`,
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES]
})
class MyApp {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have a look at [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html#!#stq=&stp=0) Angular syntax cheat-sheet**

> `<div [class.extra-sparkle]="isDelightful">`
>
> Binds the presence of the
>   CSS class extra-sparkle on the element to the truthiness of the
>   expression isDelightful.

**In your case it would be something like this**

```
 @Component({
      template: `<ng2-select [class.my-class]="shouldClassExist"></ng2-select>`,
      selector: 'my-app',
      directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    class MyApp {
      shouldClassExist: boolean;

      changeClass(){
        //do something here
        this.shouldClassExist = true;    // set true or false
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFKKPAhkemQF5oHbp25X?p=preview) to see why your provided solution doesn't work?

Comment: Because to limit the reach of the styles defined inside a component to the template of that component angular adds the ID of the component to the defined styles' selectors. so your style becomes `.red[_ngcontent-gxg-2] {color: red}` and because you defined this inside `selector` component but style is applied in `AppComponent`. So it doesn't apply to it.

Comment: you can't  do this `jasonlyvia`. What A Singh has suggested it right.

Comment: @jasonslyvia look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nk07egfV5t7EA1L1RzYp?p=preview) plnkr.  It's called viewEncapsulation. which is ON by default. But you can turn it off. Now it works.

Comment: @jasonslyvia, another option is to move your `.red` definition into AppComponent (i.e., add a `styles` definition to AppComponent instead of the child component), then you wouldn't need to use ViewEncapsulation in the child component.